# Select clause in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to parse a dataset that has three columns in it called Store, Rate and then OHUNIT.  I use SQL to get the dataset and then I am using a datarow and a filter to select the data that I need.

Here is the code:

```
DataRow[] _dr = null;
string filter = "";
 filter = "Store = 6 and Rate = " + row["RATE"].ToString();
 _dr = ds.Tables[0].Select(filter);
    if (_dr.Length > 0)
    {
        DSOH = Convert.ToDecimal(_dr[0]["OHUNIT"]);
        TOTOH += DSOH;
    }
    else
        DSOH = 0;
```

In this the rate can be a number from 1-5, U or O.  When I run it the filter gets updated to "Store = 6 and Rate = 3". But then when it hits this line

```
 _dr = ds.Tables[0].Select(filter);
```

I get this error:

An exception of type 'System.Data.EvaluateException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code.
Cannot perform '=' operation on System.String and System.Int32.

Comment: What are the types of the columns?  The filter is assuming they're both numeric.

Comment: Just checked and Rate is a char type, Store is a decimal.  Tried converting the row["Rate"] to an int instead of a string and still got the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a comment above:

> Rate is a char type

In that case the error seems to be suggesting that the filter requires quotes around the value, just like any SQL filter clause:

```
filter = "Store = 6 and Rate = '" + row["RATE"].ToString() + "'";
```

Comment: Literally just tried this and it worked! But thanks! I will check this one!  I do not know why I didn't think of this right away.

Comment: @nminar: I figured the comment exchange above would have been plenty for you to fix it :)  But hopefully this can help future visitors.